# Is there a wait to "break" a wait loop from Get-Content in powershell?

Tags: powershell

Is there a wait to "break" a wait loop from Get-Content in powershell ?

```
Get-Content "$PSScriptRoot\out.txt" -Wait
```

`out.txt` has a fixed number of lines being written, and I want to stop the loop when the end is reached.
So far, I need to send a signal with "ctrl+c" to finish.
In pseudo code that would be something like

```
Get-Content "$PSScriptRoot\out.txt" -WaitUntil 9
Get-Content "$PSScriptRoot\out.txt" -WaitUntilMatch "^LastOutput"
```

so when `9` lines are output, we break the loop. Or when a certain regex match is reached, can we break the loop ?

Comment: `Get-Content -Path "$PSScriptRoot\out.txt" -Wait -TotalCount 9`

Comment: @TheIncorrigible1 This will only work if the file doesn't contain 9 lines already. If it does, It will just give you the first 9 lines of the file, and the -wait switch will have no effect.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can pipe the value from Get-Content to ForEach-Object, and break when a condition is met.

For example, if you want to break  when a certain regex match is reached, you can use the following:

```
Get-Content -Path "$PSScriptRoot\out.txt" -Wait | ForEach-Object {$_ ; if($_ -Match "some regex"){break} }
```

In case you want to to break after n lines, then as Bruce answerd, you can use `Select-Object -Frist n`.

Notice that if the file already contains content which satisfies the conditions, and you want only the new data that is being added to the file, you should also use the `-tail` option.

For example, if the file already contains 9 lines, and you want only the first 9 lines that will be added to the file **after** you run the command, then use:

```
Get-Content -Path "$PSScriptRoot\out.txt" -Wait -tail 1 | select -skip 1 -first 9
```

With `-tail 1`, the command will output only the last line of the file and the new data that will be added to the file afterwards. `-skip 1` is used to filter out the last line and only output the new data.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `Select-Object -First n` to stop the pipeline after n items:

```
Get-Content -Path "$PSScriptRoot\out.txt" -Wait  | select -first 9
```

(Though I like the idea of adding `-WaitUntil` and `-WaitMatch` to `Get-Content`. It might be worth opening an issue on the [PowerShell Github repo](http://github.com/powershell/powershell))